# Irregular expansion of fixed main navigation bar

Tags: css, navbar, blogger

I don't have much experience in coding but eventually I manage to create a blog in Blogger. After several attempts to customize, I run into a problem with my main navigation bar. The problem is unless you are at the top of the page, the bar will expand as you scroll and cover the post underneath, which is extremely annoying.

I notice that my three-line navicon ("fa fa-bars") is also having a problem which is being not in the middle of the bar so I use my browser inspect function and find out that the container box ("indzign-box") is misplaced.

[image: Illustration picture]

Is it that container box cause the irregular expansion of my navbar or something else and how to fix it?

```css
/* Main Navigation */
nav.fixnavbar{position:relative;display:block;width:100%;background:#778595;z-index:99;padding:0;margin-bottom:0;font-size:0;opacity:1;}
.fixednav{position:relative;margin:0 auto;padding:0;max-width:1010px}
.fixednav li{display:inline-block;}
.fixednav li a{display:inline-block;padding:20px;color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase;}
.fixednav li a:hover{background:#6c7a89;color:#fff}
.nav-icon{display:none}
nav.fixnavbar.main-nav-scrolled{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;opacity:.97;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0)}

/* Box Info */
.fixednav li.indzign-box{color:rgba(255,255,255,1);z-index:2;font:normal 24px FontAwesome;cursor:pointer;float:right;display:inline-block;padding:18.5px 20px;transition:all 0.5s ease-out}
.icon-box{background-color:rgba(66,133,244,0.8);padding:8px 13px;border-radius:100%;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-right:5px}
.icon-box:hover{color:white;background-color:rgba(66,133,244,1)}
.notif-info{background-color:rgba(245,245,245,0.5);border:1px solid #eee;padding:5px 8px;margin-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;text-align:left}
.notif-info:hover{opacity:0.8}
.notif-info p{font-size:11px;color:#555;margin:0;margin-top:-5px;padding-left:40px}
#indzignbox{background:#fff;color:#333;font-size:13px;top:-381px;right:306px;padding:20px;position:fixed;width:320px;box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);z-index:100;transition:all .5s}
#indzignbox .closebox{background:none;color:#999;padding:4px 6px}
```

```html
<nav class='fixnavbar'>
  <button class='nav-icon-position nav-icon' type='button'>
    <span class='icon-line'/>
    <span class='icon-line'/>
    <span class='icon-line'/>
  </button>
  <ul class='fixednav' id='togglemenu'>
    <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li class='indzign-box' onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;indzignbox&apos;).style.top=&apos;60px&apos;;document.getElementById(&apos;count-box&apos;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;'><i class='fa fa-bars'/></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/list'>List bài viết</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/kinh-nghiem'>Kinh nghiệm</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/review'>Gundam Reviews</a></li>                        
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is the padding property of `.fixednav li.indzign-box`

Just change the padding from `padding:18.5px 20px;` to `padding:8px 20px;`